# Efficient overloading in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I wonder which of the two strategies below is the most efficient for overloading a function (here the function teX in my example).

1. Using `data` and pattern matching:

   ```
   data TeX
     = TeXt String
     | TeXmath String
     deriving (Show,Read,Eq)
   teX (TeXt t)    = t
   teX (TeXmath t) = "$$" ++ t ++ "$$"
   ```
2. Or using a bit of abstraction:

   ```
   class TeX t where
     teX :: t -> String

   newtype TeXt = TeXt String
     deriving (Show,Read,Eq)
   instance TeX TeXt where
     teX (TeXt t) = t

   newtype TeXmath = TeXmath String
     deriving (Show,Read,Eq)
   instance TeX TeXmath where
     teX (TeXmath t) = "$$" ++ t ++ "$$"
   ```

Surely the first is easier to use and the second easier to enrich; but I wonder if one will run faster than the other, or if Haskell will implement them in the exact same way.

Comment: the second is not really what typeclasses are about, looks like you are trying to replicate classes in OOP

Comment: You shouldn't be concerned with performance in that way, not for something like rendering to `String`s: those are intrinsically so slow that any overhead that may be imposed by the class dictionary is neglectable. In fact, you really shouldn't render to `String` here, rather to [`Text`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/latest/doc/html/Data-Text.html) (or [`LaTeX`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HaTeX/3.5/doc/html/Text-LaTeX-Base-Syntax.html#t:LaTeX), duh).

Comment: I am with Arjan, the second seems like a really bad idea. See for example the way a type like [this one](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-types/blob/master/Text/Pandoc/Definition.hs)  (githubpandoc repo) is rendered by something like your `teX` function [here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/master/src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/LaTeX.hs)

Comment: The latter module is a bit complicated because it covers so much, but note that that the approach has an extensibility the classes you envisage don't:  how would you introduce a function `html :: t -> String' and `markdown :: t -> String` and like functions such as are defined elsewhere in that package?

Answer (score 5):

The first one is more space-efficient. Calling a function defined in a type class is equivalent to invoking a method in an object-oriented language: any functions which are polymorphic on the type `TeX t` (i.e., has `TeX t =>` in the type signature) will have to carry around an extra, implicit parameter, namely a dictionary storing the particular methods for a given instance of `TeX`.

Now, about faster? I'd imagine that for programs with a small memory footprint, the first way is marginally faster due to less memory allocation and one less indirection to actually calling the `teX` function. For allocation-heavy programs, the same would hold until the program hits some memory allocation threshold—which the first version would hit later, and would therefore be somewhat faster once the 2nd one hits that point.

Comment: I think this answer is over-simplified.  Due to inlining and type-specialization, it's quite possible that the `TeX` dictionary will be resolved entirely at compile-time.  As to performance, I would guess that the extra indirection has a much larger impact than allocation.   But I wouldn't rely on my intuition for this.

Comment: That is true, but not fundamentally true; One could (should) work hard to suit the the fancy of the optimizer, but I don't count that as overcoming the fundamental overhead of using type classes, because it couldn't be reliably ensured.